# What is dynamic equilibrium actually?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

Recently I have asked question sort of like that:

> Is thermodynamic equilibrium static or **dynamic** ?

But then I wanted to realize what actually a dynamic equilibrium is. I read the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_equilibrium), but it wrote only in the perspective of chemical equilibrium, like

> When the rate of production of product is equal to that of reactants,it is called dynamic equilibrium.

But this definition can't be used in thermal equilibrium or mechanical equilibrium. So,what is the definition?? Plz help.

Comment: a body with constant velocity(no friction/damping etc)  is in dynamic equilibrium in the sense of mechanical equilibrium, isnt it ?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155271/2451

Comment: The notion of dynamic equilibria is very restrictive (it's probably a very old idea that never really worked) and it simply doesn't describe the incredible complexity of open systems. I think you would be better served by looking into a book on complex systems to get an idea about the multitude of phenomena that are out there. Something like Hermmann Haken's "Information and Self-Organization: A Macroscopic Approach to Complex Systems" might give you the idea.

Comment: Consider a terrestrial planet with an atmosphere in a stable orbit a few billion years or more after formation. The planet is certainly not in thermal equilibrium; the temperature at the core remains close to that of the surface of the Sun while the temperature at some points in the atmosphere can be downright cold. Yet the planet's surface and atmosphere are more or less in a state of local equilibrium, possibly with a memory (e.g., ice ages may involve a memory).

Answer (score 5):

In thermodynamics the quantities we conventionally use, like Gibbs free energy or entropy, are statistical averages. Remember that our systems are ensembles of [around $10^{23}$ particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) all buzzing around at random. If you could measure, for exammple, the Gibbs free energy with sufficient accuracy you'd find that it varied randomly with time and only the time averaged value was constant.

This is why equilibria in thermodynamic systems are described as *dynamic*. The equilibrium state is actually just a time average and on very short time scales the system is fluctuating very slightly away from the equilibrium state.

However when we consider mechanical systems we normally treat these as containing just a few 
elementary objects, where by *elementary* I mean the objects are not treated as being composed of smaller objects. And this is normally entirely reasonable. Yes, obviously a lever (or whatever objects you're finding the equilibrium for) is made of atoms, but in a solid the atoms don't move away from their equilbrium positions as they do in a gas or liquid. So treating the objects in our free body diagram as simple elementary objects is fine. In this case the equilibrium is static, because all the objects involved are static.

So basically a dynamic equilibrium is a time average of many small objects undergoing random motions and static equilibrium is a time independant state of a few objects that aren't moving.

Comment: Sir, thermodynamic equilibrium is composed of thermal,mechanical & chemical equilibrium. Now if the former is dynamic, will I not say, mechanical equilibrium is also dynamic?

Comment: This is what I doubt. I also thought that it is static. But then thermodynamic equilibrium can't be called dynamic as mechanical equilibrium is a part of it:-(

Comment: @user36790: If you consider the degrees of freedom (DOF) of your system, then in a typical mechanical system we can ignore the DOF of the atoms making up the levers, pulleys etc because at the temperatures involved those DOF cannot be excited. Thus our system has few degrees of freedom and can be traeted as stationary. In a thermodynamic system the DOF of individual atoms do need to be taken into account and the individual atoms cannot be treated as stationary. This makes the equilibrium dynamic.